# setInterval on a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
for (var i=list.length; i>=0; i--){
    //do something....                      
}
```

I want to use a setInterval to make this process take 1 whole min no matter how many items are in the list. So if there are 10 items it would trigger every 6sec, 30items, every two seconds, etc.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you give some background info to what you're trying to accomplish? To take exactly one minute, it would depend entirely on what you are doing every iteration and how long a single iteration takes and it might be very hard to achieve.

Comment: Also make sure you don't put any mission critical code on it, and don't assume it will always fire as you planned. I'm not sure if it's implemented yet in Chrome, but browsers can optimise resource usage when your page is on a background tab, and might end up calling your timers with bigger intervals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this could be done:

```
var list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var timeFrame = 60000;
var interval = timeFrame / (list.length-1);
var i = 0;

(function iterate () {
    if (list.length > i) {
        console.log(list[i]);
        i++;
    }
    setTimeout(iterate, interval);
})();
```

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WgC7Y/)

I am not sure if this is what you're looking for, but this will "iterate" through all items in the list, without using `for` loop, in the given timeframe. The function will always "call itself" using `setTimeout`. The timeout is calculated in the beginning based on the number of items.

This solution is much more "trustable" than `setInterval`. The next timeout will be set when the previous action is already done, so it won't stack up.

Comment: 1 minute is 60000 milliseconds

Comment: @mplungjan Yeah, just had this value for the testing :). Forgot to change it back, thanks.

Comment: You can put your iteration state variables into a closure to avoid using globals. You don't want to do what I did in Ocamel. :)

Comment: @DarthJDG :D That's for sure :). I just wanted to give a quick example (or I assumed that all this code will go into a function).

Answer (score 1):

```
var totalItem = list.length;
setInterval(function(){ alert('');}, 60000/totalItem);
```

Comment: Alert is a blocking instruction. I fixed your spelling too

Answer (score -1):

You'd do

```
function code(i) {
    return function() { alert(i); };
}

var period = 60 * 1000 / (list.length - 1);
for (var i=list.length; i>=1; i--){ 
    setTimeout(code(list[i - 1]), period * (i - 1));
}
```

Comment: `setInterval`s first argument should be the function, the second the delay.

Comment: Will execute the function with no delay. See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RFw8A/). `setTimeout` either expects a function or a string (which is not advised to be used, it is like `eval`) as the first argument. You are calling a function instead of giving a function as an argument, so unless `code()` returns a function, this won't work.

Comment: funny thing is as i finished hammering the time division logic i thought to myself "the nitpickers will put me on a stick because they'll assume that code doesn't return a closure and that it's there out my sheer ignorance"

Comment: I am one of the "nitpickers". If I see a bad code example, I will downvote and leave a comment about the problems in the code. If the answer is corrected, I will remove my downvote (like I did here). It is nothing personal, but a bad code example won't help the OP.

Answer (score -2):

Try something like the following:

```
var interval = 2;
for (var i=list.length; i>=0; i--){
    setTimeout(your_code_here(), i*interval);
}
```

Comment: This would not work because you immediately execute the function. Remove the () from your_code_here - also you execute this in x*2 milliseconds.

Comment: Comment to post by @i100: I don't think this would work: var interval = 2; for (var i=list.length; i>=0; i--){ setTimeout(your_code_here(), i*interval); } when the "your_code_here()" is waiting for executing, the loop is still going on.
and the loop will be done in a really short time(maybe 1ms or shorter, depends on your cpu)...